# How to store data of label tag into database

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

i create a form where i upload data into database but now i want to add the data through some clickable label i want to just click on the label then the data of the label will store in their individual property. i create this in asp.netcore mvc.

html:

```
<label for="#">Features</label>
        <div class="p_features">
            
            <label >Drawing Room</label>
            <label >Prayer Room</label>
            <label >Laundry Room</label>
            <label>Store Room</label>
            <label>Study Room</label>
            <label>Kitchn</label>
            <label>Gym</label>
            <label>Launge</label>
            <label>Servent Quarters</label>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.p_features {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

    .p_features label {
        padding: 10px 13px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        color: var(--primary-color);
        border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
        background-color: white;
    }
```

Here how i want to add the data[image]

Comment: You can create a click event for labels and on click write a ajax call to pass data from label to backend code for saving in database

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could add a class to the label, then you could use jquery's click method to get the label value and then use ajax to post to the backend mvc controller.

More details, you could refer to below example:

MVC controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ajaxupload([FromForm]string value)
    {
        return Ok();

    }
```

View:

```
 <label for="#">Features</label>
        <div class="p_features">
            
            <label class="upload" >Drawing Room</label>
            <label  class="upload" >Prayer Room</label>
            <label  class="upload">Laundry Room</label>
            <label  class="upload">Store Room</label>
            <label  class="upload">Study Room</label>
            <label  class="upload">Kitchn</label>
            <label  class="upload">Gym</label>
            <label  class="upload">Launge</label>
            <label  class="upload">Servent Quarters</label>
        </div>

 

@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(function(){
    $(".upload").click(function(e){
    
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);
   
         $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "/Home/ajaxupload",  
                data: {value: e.target.innerHTML},  
                success: function(response) {  
                   alert("OK");
                },  
                failure: function(response) {  
                    alert(response.responseText);  
                },  
                error: function(response) {  
                    alert(response.responseText);  
                }  
            });  
        

    });

    });

</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: But i want to add thier value into the property using asp-for